# Triggering a click recursively on d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to recursively trigger an event on d3.js.

This (no d3.js involved) works:
http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/98HmT/

```
$("#b1").on("click", function() {
        var elem = $(this);    
        console.log(elem);
        console.log("Pressed");
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(elem); $(elem).trigger("click")}, 1000)
 });
```

But this (on d3.js) doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/bmdKW/

```
d3.select("#node1").on("click", function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        console.log(elem);
        console.log("Pressed");
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(elem); $(elem).trigger("click")}, 1000)
});
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
It seems that jQuery's "trigger" doesn't dispatch real events; it only calls its own listeners. So, it is not able to see the "click" event handler set up by d3.

Comment: Try elem.trigger("click") as elem is already a jQuey Object .. That should not be a problem but try if that changes anything

Comment: @Sushanth-- No, it doesn't change anything, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try having the click event call a function that then starts the looping:

```
d3.select("#node1").on("click", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    console.log(elem);
    console.log("Pressed");
    qwerty();
});

function qwerty() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("looping");
        qwerty2()
    }, 1000)
};

function qwerty2() {
    console.log("part 2");
    qwerty();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this certainly works. But I would like to know why the code I posted doesn't. Here you are introducing 2 more functions and things can become a bit more complicated if you want something to be passed between them. Thanks anyway for the tip.